# How to create a custom Http module or handler for use with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use a custom http module to process incoming requests in my MVC 4 application. If the user comes to any page in the application I want to check for the presence of a particular cookie and redirect to a different page if the cookie isn't present. Once the user has visited the specified page and filled in required information the cookie will be added to the session. Since I want this behavior on each page (controller/action) I thought a custom HttpModule would do the trick. I could check for the presence of the cookie in BeginRequest and redirect if necessary and not have to add this check at the beginning of every action method.

The problem I have is I only want to do this for requests for valid Controller/Actions. I don't want to check for the cookie if an image or javascript file is being requested. Since the url for controller/views doesn't have a file extension, what do I key off of? How can I determine if the url is a valid route or just a request for something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that you need a custom HTTP module.  It seems to me you ought to be able to accomplish this with an [ActionFilter](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) -- maybe a customized version of [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)?

These can be registered "globally" to be applied to all controllers / actions.  If you create a new MVC project, there should be a `FilterConfig` class in the `App_Start` folder that adds a `HandleErrorAttribute` as a global filter.